# Jasmine getting undefined array from scripts file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I'm defining my array `randomIDs` in my scripts file with this function:

```
let randomIDs = [];
let letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

function zeroPadd(value) {
    return value < 10 ? "0" + value : value;
}

function randomise() {
    playButton.prop("disabled", false).text("Play");
    musicGrid.find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(".bar").removeClass("playing");
    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        randomIDs[i - 1] = letters[randomIndex] + zeroPadd(i);
    }
    randomIDs.forEach(id => $(`#${id}`).addClass("selected"));
    createSequence();
}
```

After this function is called, my array is for example:

```
["c01", "h02", "l03", "i04", "g05", "f06", "h07", "b08", "h09", "i10", "l11", "i12"]
```

(Letters are random, numbers are sequential from 1 to 12).

I want to run tests with Jasmine, but in my Jasmine html file my `randomIDs` array is

```
["undefined01", "undefined02", "undefined03", "undefined04", "undefined05", "undefined06", "undefined07", "undefined08", "undefined09", NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

I didn't get to write any specs yet, but I get console errors for jasmine attempting to find the files using that array.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `zeroPadd` come from? Is that your function? Or are you using r and wanted `zeroPad`? Or ???

Comment: This is zeroPadd:

`function zeroPadd(value) {
    return value < 10 ? "0" + value : value;
}`

Comment: Re zeroPadd: The quotes around the zero (`"0"`) makes the zero a string instead of a number which results in your `NaN` (not a number) values. Just get rid of the quotes. Not the only problem, but a contributor.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it needs to be a string as it will populate the name of the files, which end up being for example 'c01.mp3'

Comment: Where and how is your `letters` array defined? Looks like it is empty when running Jasmine. Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry for being incomplete. I edited my question. The function works fine (as I said) in my scripts.js, but it's undefined in Jasmine. I just don't know why :)